# Binding to a combobox with specified content

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm wondering how can I bind to a `ComboBox` item when it's content is specified. I'm able to save the content to the database but when I try to re-enter the record, the `ComboBox` won't change at all to the `SelectedItem`.

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Duration, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" Style="{StaticResource CombBox}" MinWidth="60">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="15 Minutes"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="30 Minutes"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="45 Minutes"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1 Hour"/>
</ComboBox>

public string Duration { get { return Entity.Duration; } set { Entity.Duration = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(); } }
```

Am I not setting my bindings correct?

Comment: replace ComboBoxItem's with object of type `Duration`

Comment: Hi @HosseinNarimaniRad I'm not sure what that means exactly. Could you give me an example please.

Comment: What he means is instead of using `ComboBoxItem`, use `String` instead.

Comment: You are using both the selectedItem and selectedIndex, I'm not sure whether it's a meaningful job or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** In you xaml use this namespace `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

**Second:** change your ComboBox to this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Duration, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <sys:String>15 Minutes</sys:String>
    <sys:String>30 Minutes</sys:String>
    <sys:String>45 Minutes</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

**Third:** How did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`? It seems you don't send the properties name as string to the Notify mechanism. It should be something like this (insted of `NotifyOfPropertyChange()`)

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Duration"));
```

Comment: Sweet this worked!!!! Thank you. I've used caliburn implementation of property change. It's alot cleaner in the back. You don't have to specify the variable like INotify you would have to use OnPropertyChange("Duration")

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the binding mode, Mode = TwoWay

For more info go to 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps